# How to limit the textfield to 100 with special characters in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a text field that can have these types of values:

```
>35%
<=60%
=55%
=100%
```

I want to set the max limit of the numbers to 100. How can I do that?

Here's the textfield:

```
<TextField
  placeholder="=100%"
  variant="outlined"
  value={data}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, shaluj: Did you ever come up with a solution?  Did my answer below help?  Let me know, in case others have the same problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with [**`replaceAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to remove the extra characters, use [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to cast it to an integer, then do a simple number comparison to determine what to display.  For example...

```js
var input = ">50%";
const regex = />|%|=/ig;
var number = parseInt(input.replaceAll(regex, ''), 10);

var useable = number > 100 ? '=100%' : input ;

console.log("Printable value... " + useable);
```

And then you display it using the new variable.

```
<TextField
  placeholder="=100%"
  variant="outlined"
  value={useable}
/>
```

Comment: It worked, for strings having greater than symbol. If a string is "<50%" or "=50%". It is showing NaN

Comment: Hi, shalu j: I just updated my answer to handle that case.  I changed this, `const regex = />|%/ig;`, to this: `const regex = />|%|=/ig;`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by something like this:

```
<TextField placeholder="=100%" variant="outlined" value={data<=100?data:100} />
```

**Edit**:
I don't know where you get that data, but we assume that data is what you want to be the value of the TextField:

```
function limitMax(data, maxValue) {
  const r = /\d+/;
  let theNumber = data.match(r)[0]; //get number inside string (type is still string)
  if (parseInt(theNumber) > maxValue) {
     return data.replace(theNumber, maxValue.toString())
  }
  else return data
}

//Then
<TextField placeholder="=100%" variant="outlined" value={limitMax(data,100)} />
```

Comment: If data is a string, I believe you would want to use data.length <= 100 ? data : 100

Also note that this answer will not work if you are trying to submit to a server per se, because although you are only showing 100 chars, your component will store the complete value, which could be over 100 chars

Comment: the textfield value is not a number, it is the string with a combination of special characters and numbers. Allowed special characters are %, <, >,= and max number can be 100. I have mentioned  the possibilities in the question

Comment: @shaluj you are setting text field value manually, is it read-only?

Comment: The user enters the text field value manually.